# Is it recommended to recite 'Ya Shafi Ya Kafi' before taking a medication?

Tags: fiqh, medical, khutbah, sick

I recently came across a sermon where the narrator recommends to recite

> YA SHAAFI YA KAFI YA BAQI ( The Healer, Self-sufficient, The
> Everlasting)

for General Sickness, Deadly Diseases, Fevers, Burns or Evil Eye.

Is there any reference to this from the sunnah? How authentic is this practice?

Answer (score 0):

According to [islamqa](https://islamqa.info/ar/answers/218727/) it is not part of the sunnah to say this - meaning that this is not a  ma'thur dua or dhikr. However this phrase is essentially just supplicating to Allah using His names which is prescribed.

> ولله الأسماء الحسنى فادعوه بها
>
> And to Allah belong the best names, so invoke Him by them.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 7:180](https://quran.com/7/180?translations=20)</sup>

And part of that is to call upon Allah with those of His names which are appropriate to the situation, as demonstrated in the following ma'thur duas:

> أذهب الباس رب الناس، اشف وأنت الشافي لا شفاء إلا شفاؤك، شفاء لا يغادر سقما
>
> Take away the disease, O the Lord of the people! Cure him as You are the One Who cures. There is no cure but Yours, a cure that leaves no disease.
>
> <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:5675)</sup>

> فاغفر لي مغفرة من عندك، وارحمني إنك أنت الغفور الرحيم
>
> Bestow on me a forgiveness from You, and Have Mercy on me, You are the Forgiver, the Merciful
>
> <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:834)</sup>